# Prove $2^k+1$ divisible by 3 for odd K

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove $2^k+1$ divisible by 3 iff $k$ is odd number.

Since I need to prove both direction looks like if I need to prove it's divisible by 3 it's by induction and the other side by congruence..am I right? is there a better wat than induction? and we I still can't prove both direction... any hints?

Comment: Try phrasing the question in terms of modular arithmetic rather than divisibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k=2m$, then $2^k=4^m\equiv 1^m\pmod 3$ and if $k=2m+1$ then $2^k=2\cdot 4^m\equiv 2\cdot 1^m\pmod 3$.

Comment: so the other way is in induction as I said?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen can I just ask for some clarification, as I am learning this subject: I read the last part as $ 2^k \equiv 2 (mod 3) $ which by definition means $ 3|(2^k - 2)$ - so how is this the same as $ 3|(2^k + 1)$? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Prove by induction that $2^k\equiv(-1)^k\pmod 3$.

Comment: Actually, induction is unnecessary.  It suffices to consider that $2 \equiv -1$.

Comment: @Andrew: Depends on what the OP already knows about modular arithmetic.

Comment: @A.S Actuallu induction *is* used in such modular proofs, but it is simply hidden in some lemma (here in the proof of the [Congrence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\, a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a^n\equiv b^n,\,$ for $\,a,b = 2,\, -1).\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $4 \equiv 1 \mod 3$, so $2^{k+2} \equiv \ldots $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ 1\!-\!(-2)\mid 1\!-\!(-2)^{2n+1}$